# Golang Gorm rollback is not working in nested transaction

Tags: go, go-gorm

From what I read and understood from the docs that Gorm support nested transaction rollback, which means that if any of the transaction fail, it should rollback everything / cancel all commits right? However it is not working as how I understood it.

order.go

```
tx := db.Begin()
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        }
    }()

    // Create some data in orders table
    if err := tx.Model(&models.Order{}).Create(map[string]any{"user_id": 121345}).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    // Create some data in order_payments table
    if err := tx.Model(&models.OrderPayment{}).Create(map[string]any{"amount": "zzsadq"}).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()

        // When this fails, it does not rollback the data in orders table, there are still new data
        // being created in the orders table, as I understood, it should rollback all the
        // transactions

        return err
    }

    return tx.Commit().Error
```

Is there something missing, or am I not understanding correctly? If so, how can I rollback all the previous transactions if any of them fails? I need to rollback everything for data consistency. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: As I see in your code you do everything in one transaction and there are no nested ones, do you change the tx variable somewhere?

Comment: So I'm following the example stated in the docs https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#A-Specific-Example how am I suppose to do it? so that if any of the create fail, then cancel everything

Comment: I also did try to do it like this https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#Nested-Transactions but also same result, it's not rolling back the previous create transaction, it is still being stored in the table when the second create transaction fail

Comment: Your code looks alright to me. I also tried to replicate the bug but found no success in doing that. Are you sure that when creating OrderPayment you are getting some error from database?